# Como adicionar um novo dicionário dentro de outro dicionário?

Tags: python, dicionário

```
ini={"MAIN":{}}
ini['MAIN']['Nome']="Jaque"
print ini
```

Saída do print: `{'MAIN': {'Nome': 'Jaque'}}`

Como colocar um novo dicionário dentro desse que já existe?

Quero ter isso: `{'MAIN': {'Nome': 'Jaque'} 'NOVO_DICT': {} }`

Comment: Não seria `ini['NOVO_DICT'] = {}`? Não consegui entender muito bem a dúvida.

Comment: Ou ainda `ini.update( { 'NOVO_DICT':{} } )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que você quer ter isso:

```
{'MAIN': {'Nome': 'Jaque'}, 'NOVO_DICT': {}} #vígula antes de 'NOVO_DICT'
```

Se eu estiver certo, logo, é só você adicionar um novo valor à entrada `NOVO_DICT` da variável `ini`. Assim:

```
ini={"MAIN":{}}
ini['MAIN']['Nome']="Jaque"
ini['NOVO_DICT']={}
print ini
```

Ao atribuir `{}` à entrada `NOVO_DICT` da variável `ini`, o Python automaticamente já cria essa entrada caso ela não existir.

Comment: isso mesmo! Valeu